# Paging UIScrollView - How to flick multiple pages at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipickerviewcontroller

I have a paging scrollview much like [Apple's Page Control example project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) which I have adapted into a horizontal picker.  I would really like the ability to scroll through many pages per flick gesture instead of one-at-a-time, much like how UIPickerViews work.  Looking for some guidance on how to approach this.  Thanks!

Comment: can you have look at this Mr.Capikaw https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 1):

**First here best** [Source Code](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

It could be that whatever is setting those numbers in there, is not greatly impressed by you setting the `contentOffset` under its hands. So it just goes on setting what it thinks should be the contentOffset for the next instant - without verifying if the contentOffset has changed in the meantime.

I would subclass `UIScrollView` and put the magic in the `setContentOffset` method. In my experience all content-offset changing passes through that method, even the content-offset changing induced by the internal scrolling. Just do [super `setContentOffset`:..] at some point to pass the message on to the real `UIScrollView`.

Maybe if you put your shifting action in there it will work better. You could at least detect the 3000-off setting of `contentOffset`, and fix it before passing the message on. If you would also override the contentOffset method, you could try and see if you can make a virtual infinite content size, and reduce that to real proportions "under the hood".

[This is also helpful for you..!!!](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html)